# Azure WebJobs NuGet Package Error

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-webjobs

I would like to know if someone has experienced running error on Azure WebJobs Queue sample on Visual Studio templates.

The sample running to issue after I updated all the packages on NuGet manager.

This is the error message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage is deployed incorrectly. Are you missing a Table Service assembly (Microsoft.Data.Services.Client, Microsoft.Data.OData or Microsoft.Data.Edm) or a related binding redirect?
  Source=Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.AzureStorageDeploymentValidator.Validate()
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.JobHostConfigurationExtensions.CreateStaticServices(JobHostConfiguration config)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost.InitializeServices()
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost.<InitializeHostAsync>d__44.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost.<StartAsyncCore>d__25.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost.Start()
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost.RunAndBlock()
   at QueueSample.Program.Main() in C:\Users\adity\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\AzureQueueStorage\QueueSample\Program.cs:line 28

Inner Exception 1:
TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DataServices.TableServiceContext' from assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
```

This is the list of installed packages:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core" version="2.0.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Core" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.8.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.8.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" version="5.8.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Win32.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="NETStandard.Library" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="11.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.AppContext" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Collections" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Collections.Concurrent" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Console" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Debug" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" version="4.4.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Tools" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Tracing" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Globalization" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Globalization.Calendars" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.IO" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.IO.Compression" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.IO.Compression.ZipFile" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.IO.FileSystem" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Linq" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Linq.Expressions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Net.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Net.Sockets" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.ObjectModel" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Reflection" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Resources.ResourceManager" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Runtime" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Handles" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Numerics" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates" version="4.3.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.8.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encoding.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Text.RegularExpressions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Threading" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Timer" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Xml.ReaderWriter" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Xml.XDocument" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="WindowsAzure.Storage" version="9.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

When I using default templates and packages, it is running without error.
After I have updated the NuGet packages, it is running error like above.

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Message=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage is deployed incorrectly
>
> TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DataServices.TableServiceContext' from assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

According to your error message, I suppose  the issue may be related with the compatibility.

TableServiceContext has been deprecated since version 4.0 and was removed in version 9.0 as part of dropping OData dependencies. You'd better use the compatible version for packages(such as WindowsAzure.Storage 8.7.0). For more details about this issue, you could read this [article](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/628).

Answer (score 3):

My problem was that I had an outdated nuget package. I tried to uninstall the nuget package, found it's dependency and from this I upgraded

`Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs, Version=2.0.0.0`

to

`Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs, Version=2.2.0.0`