# Azure WebJobs useTimers method not available in .net core 2.0

Tags: azure-storage, azure-webjobs

I am using Microsoft.azure.webjobs (3.0.0-beta1-10941) in a .net core 2 console app. The aim is to create a azure web job,

```
        var config = new JobHostConfiguration();

        if (config.IsDevelopment)
        {
            config.UseDevelopmentSettings();
        }

        config.UseTimers();

        var host = new JobHost(config);
        host.RunAndBlock();
```

The config.UseTimer() is expected a reference of Microsoft.Azure.WebHost.Host but it needs 2.1.0.0. If i add this by removed beta version 3.0.0-beta1-10941 then host.runandblock() falls over at WindowsAzure.Storage incorrectly deployed install edm, data, or data.services.

I installed the dependencies but still no luck

I have downgraded windowsAzure.Storage to lower than 9 but same issue.

[Azure WebJobs NuGet Package Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49168753/azure-webjobs-nuget-package-error)

Any ideas how to resolved config.UseTimes() in .net core 2.0?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Any ideas how to resolved config.UseTimes() in .net core 2.0?

In your case you could use the [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions/3.0.0-beta4) Version 3.0.0-beta4.
I also do a demo for it. The following is detail steps.

1.Create a net core 2.0 console application.

2.Add the following code in the Program.cs file.

```
var config = new JobHostConfiguration();

if (config.IsDevelopment)
{
     config.UseDevelopmentSettings();
}
config.UseTimers();
config.DashboardConnectionString ="storage connectionstring";
config.StorageConnectionString = "storage connectionstring";
var host = new JobHost(config);
host.RunAndBlock();
```

3. Add the Functions.cs file to the project.

```
 public class Functions
 {
      public static void CronJob([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")] TimerInfo timer)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cron job fired!");
        }
  }
```

4. Test it on my side.

[image]

Comment: Fantastic answer and gave steps to resolve the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Check [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to). There are solutions for 2.x and 3.x.

For 3.x can be used "b.AddTimers();" Example:

```
static async Task Main()
{
    var builder = new HostBuilder();
    builder.UseEnvironment(EnvironmentName.Development);

    builder.ConfigureLogging((context, b) =>
    {
        b.AddConsole();
    });
    builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
    {
        b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices(); 
        b.AddAzureStorage();
        b.AddTimers();
    });
    var host = builder.Build();
    using (host)
    {
        await host.RunAsync();
    }
}
```

The time-triggered method: (need to be in a static class)

```
   public  static  class TimeTrigger
    {
        // Runs once every 10 seconds
        public static void TimerJob([TimerTrigger("00:00:10")] TimerInfo timer)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Timer job fired!");
        }

    }
```